# PHP параллельные циклы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Можно ли используя php запустить несколько разных циклов одновременно?

Comment: Насколько мне известно встроенными функциями - нет. Но можно использовать внешние библиотеки, например PHPThreads

Comment: Можно, а вам зачем?)